# After updating Excel I'm no longer able to get the data using a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, excel, database

I updated the version of Excel to 2016 and now I am unable to simply paste SQL query.

The "Get Data" button is missing.

[image]

**This is how it was before an update:**

Before, I could easily go to "Data"--> GetData --> From Database --> From SQL Server Database...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you specify a server (first box)?

Comment: the last 2 snips its how it used to be before update

Answer (score 1):

To get to the same window you can use "New Query" button instead of "Get Data".

Also you can to click on "From Other Sources" and then 1st option will be SQL Server:

[image]